# Startup and Wi-Fi problem with email, apps

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

Had to grab a Samsung Galaxy Discover prepaid phone with 4.0.4 as a quick replacement.  Only problem is whenever I power up the phone, my Gmail and ISP's email accounts won't sync and my weather widget won't refresh.  Idisable Wi-Fi service and then everything starts working immediately.  I can then start Wi-Fi and it seems like everything works via wifi from then on until my next on/off.  No other carrier or Wi-Fi issues that I can see.

Any thoughts on the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution as to the underlying problem -- but a possible work-around involving [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (or a similar automation app which could do the same):

- Condition:

  - On Startup
  - If Wi-Fi On
- Task:

  - Wi-Fi Off
  - Wait 15 sec
  - Wi-Fi On

This at least should save you from having to do it manually everytime.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I will give that a whirl if I cannot find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: You're welcome -- that was the idea behind it.